# Как получить доступ по Name к Grid если он в ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

Я нашел отличный способ добавления удаления колонок и столбцов на [сайте MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/manipulate-columns-and-rows-by-using-columndefinitionscollections) .
Подскажите как заставить его работать если Grid  с Name внутри шаблона ItemsControl?
Он прекрасно работает если код такой:

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="MyGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ShowGridLines="true" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

И MyGrid1 вообще не видит если код такой:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="MyGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ShowGridLines="true" Width="300" Height="300">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Content}" Command="{Binding Command}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Уточнение: 
Как связать с моим ColumnDefinition и RowDefinition ?

```
 RowDefinition rowDef1;
   ColumnDefinition colDef1;

   private void addCol(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
      grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
   }
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут имя?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Для добавления колонок и рядов в <Grid> , добавил ссылку на пример с MSDN. Я хоть и даю имя Grid но с бихайна ее невидно.

Comment: Вы так и не поняли мой посыл. Вы опять лезете к контролу, используя его как источник данных, а где привязки? Я ведь дал вам класс расширения, который позволяет привязать свойство к Grid и тем самым расширить его. Помните, что я говорил про MVVM? По его правилам вы сейчас делаете очень грубое нарушение. Текущий ваш код является смесью ужасного подхода и более менее нормального подхода, вы уж тогда определитесь что хотите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я неделю назад не знал что такое c# wpf а вы мне про MVVM ) . Что я только не пробовал и создавать класс с ColumnDefinitionCollection  и так как вы говорили. второй пример с ячейками выглядит замечательно но он не работает.

Comment: Понимаете в чем дело... Вы можете написать `<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />` и после `MyTextBox.Text = "Привет мир!"`, но как видите, контрол содержит в себе информацию, которая не очень то ему и нужна, также вы теряете ряд возможностей "мобильности" и расширяемости. В WPF 2 основных преимущества есть, это привязки и стили и не стоит ими пренебрегать. Мой пример, если правильно переписать, будет таким: `public string Text { get; } = "Привет мир!";` и тогда в XAML `<TextBox Text = "{Binding Text}"/>` и тут как видите данные лежат в простом свойстве, не затрагивая интерфейс.

Comment: Вы попробуйте, это очень просто, а MVVM это просто набор правил, которых стоит придерживаться. Его суть в том, чтобы разделить на слои (Model/View/ViewModel) все необходимое и слои не должны друг с другом контактировать. Текущий ваш вопрос, я не думаю что получится нормально решить, но если хотите, пробуйте брать коллекцию контролов, там брать все `Grid`, а там уже искать по имени нужный. Но вы ведь учитесь, так почему не учить сразу правильные вещи?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я пробовал <Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
      local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" /> Но так и не смог поменять количество во время выполнения , а наткнулся на пример MSDN, и хотел обеденить ваш пример с тем.

Comment: Как меняли? Установили `DataContext`? В классе, установленном как `RowCount` есть публичное свойство `RowCount`? Оно имеет сразу какое либо значение или задаете потом? Если потом, то имеет это свойство вызов INPC?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Прозрел ) Спасибо вам.

  <Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                          local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}">
    </Grid>
И в ViewModel или MainWindow (не знаю как правильно) . Добавьте в ответ я подтвержу. 
       public int RowCount { get; } = 25;

        public int ColumnCount { get; } = 25;

Comment: А нет, работает только при старте, а если в дальнейшем изменять количество, не работает, попробую, тот класс разобрать .

Comment: `а если в дальнейшем изменять количество, не работает` - реализуйте `INotifyPropertyChanged` и вызывайте в `set` свойства его событие, будет все меняться.

Comment: Добавьте в XAML две строки: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test1"` и `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}"`, будет наглядно видны все привязки. Также там пару замечаний: `Margin="192,37,0,0"` - очень, очень плохо, ибо вы просто двигаете элемент, не позиционируя его. Сделайте сетку, в сетку поместите что надо, установите `*Alignment` и радуйтесь, сами же `Margin` должны быть от силы не больше 20 +-. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` не нужен. Сам `.cs` файл окна по сути должен быть чистым, весь код там должен быть внутри `MainViewModel`.

Comment: Вы спросите, "а как же быть с кнопками, там ведь `Click="AddCol"`" - а команды для чего? Реализуйте `ICommand`, привязывайте. Теперь сам `MainViewModel`: `OnPropertyChanged("MyRowCount");` - `string` значение лишнее, ибо стоит `[CallerMemberName]`, который сам находит имя. `get { return mycolCoun; }` - старый век, используйте сокращения (`get => mycolCoun;`). Также я у вас видел такое: `"Кнопка" + i`, тоже уже давно такое не делают, удобней ведь `$"Кнопка {i}"`, верно?) Ну а так молодцы, разобрались, легко же было, верно?) Желаю вам дальнейших успехов в изучении C#!